# Why does Solr elevator give me an 404 error

Tags: solr

I have a Solr index created with Nutch.
When trying to configure the elevator, I get a 404 error via the Solr Web Admin.

I added that to my solrconfig.xml:

```xml
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
  <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
  <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
  <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="last-components">
    <str>elevator</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

```json
{
  "servlet":"default",
  "message":"Not Found",
  "url":"/solr/core01/elevate",
  "status":"404"
}
```

Where can the error be?